Obtain file name while using wildcard without loading file
I would like to load particular files starting with "Products" except of "Products_expired".
"Products" will have datestamp afterwards, eg: Products_202410. Right now the wildcard will read all the files within the link, I want to filter out Products_expired. Both file have over 100million lines, and would be expensive to obtain name with input_file_name() after loading the file.
In addition, if the file path has multiple files such as: Products_202409, Products_202410, Products_202411, Products_expired_202409, Products_expired_202410... I would want to ingest 3 files only: Products_202409, Products_202410, Products_202411, using Spark technology (optimization) without expensive forloops/append functions.
A solution for reference:
if spark.read.load("abfss://abc-def-g-001@testing123.dfs.core.windows.net/data/testing/PRODUCTS_Expired\_*.csv") contains "expired":
mssparkutils.notebook.exit(send_email("abcdefg@gmail.com", "expired", "failed"))
else:  
df = spark.read.load("abfss://abc-def-g-001@testing123.dfs.core.windows.net/data/testing/PRODUCTS\_*.csv")


Why don't you use synapse pipeline to get your requirement?

You can follow below approach to achieve your requirement:
List all files in file path using mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://<containerName>@<storage accountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<directory>") code, convert file_list to a list of tuples
file_data = [(f.name, f.path) for f in file_list], create DataFrame from the list of tuples, filter valid and expired files without loops using below code:
 valid_files_df = file_df.filter(file_df.name.startswith("Products") & ~file_df.name.contains("expired")) 
 expired_files_df = file_df.filter(file_df.name.contains("expired"))

Collect valid file paths using below code:
valid_files = [row.path for row in valid_files_df.collect()] 
expired_files = [row.path for row in expired_files_df.collect()]

Print the results and read and show valid files using below code:
print("Valid Files:", valid_files) 
print("Expired Files:", expired_files)
if valid_files: 
   df = spark.read.csv(valid_files)           
   df.show() 
else: 
   print("No valid files found.")

Here is the complete code for your reference:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

file_list = mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://inputs@badlss.dfs.core.windows.net/")
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("path", StringType(), True),
])
file_data = [(f.name, f.path) for f in file_list]
file_df = spark.createDataFrame(file_data, schema=schema)
valid_files_df = file_df.filter(file_df.name.startswith("Products") & ~file_df.name.contains("expired"))
expired_files_df = file_df.filter(file_df.name.contains("expired"))
valid_files = [row.path for row in valid_files_df.collect()]
expired_files = [row.path for row in expired_files_df.collect()]
print("Valid Files:", valid_files)
print("Expired Files:", expired_files)
if valid_files:
    df = spark.read.csv(valid_files)  
    df.show()  
else:
    print("No valid files found.")

You will get the output as shown below:


@Dan Wang can you check the answer, does it helpful? let me know

on databricks you can do something like this
pathh="dbfs:/FileStore/test_only/check"
new_list=[]
for x in dbutils.fs.ls(pathh):
    print(x[0])
    if ('Products' in x[0])  & (~('expired' in x[0])):
        new_list.append(x[0])

df=spark.read.csv(new_list[0:3])

